# How to get Android deep link to work?

Tags: android, deep-linking

UPDATE: so apparently this worked without any changes. Not sure why it didn't work before.

I'm following the examples in the Android docs and I just cannot get the deep link to work. I get the following error when I try to start it from adb:

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos" com.example.deeplink
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat="example://gizmos" pkg=com.example.deeplink }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat="example://gizmos" flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example.deeplink }
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.deeplink" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.example.deeplink.GizmosActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="example" android:host="gizmos" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Not that it launches, but here is what I have in GizmosActivity:

```
package com.example.deeplink;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class GizmosActivity extends Activity {

public static String TAG = "debug";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        Log.v(TAG,action+" "+data.toString());
    }

}
```

Full project is here: https://github.com/tomkincaid/Deep-Link

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A workaround would be to use qrcode: https://zxing.appspot.com/generator

Comment: @SimonMarquis: how is qrcode even remotely related to this question?

Comment: You can directly test your url-scheme. Deep links are url-scheme. Is your app already installed on the device? `adb shell pm list packages -f | grep com.example.deeplink`

Comment: Here is the official link to test deep linking with qrcode: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/test

Comment: @simon it looks like the qr only works with android-app:// urls, I need a url like example://gizmos/123

Comment: So use the first link I provided

Comment: I've tested your Eclipse project with this command `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos" com.example.deeplink` and it works. Are you sure your app is installed on your device?

Comment: @simon, it worked for you??? Thanks for much for testing it. Yes the app is on the device, but I wanted to do a clean test so deleted and now having problems with eclipse, so can't test anything. I'll have to try again and get back to you.

Comment: @TomKincaid yes a cloned your repository, and it works like a charm ;)

Comment: @simon FML, it just worked for me too. I did have the app on the device before. Anyway, thanks for you help.